# How do I serve content based on the user's search term?

Tags: seo

I don't have much experience with SEO, only building web pages.

How do I have my page load dynamic content based on the user's google search term?

For example if he searches "mobile phone definition", how does my webpage know to display the requested definition and URL to the content as a result on the Google results page?

My content is coming from a postgreSQL database and will be live queried based on the user's search term to display on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a page about mobile phone definition like `https://example.com/mobile-phone-definition`.  Any time that anybody visits this URL, your site would be programmed to show the content from your database about mobile phone definition.

You would also create other pages on your site and figure out a way to link them together so that users can navigate between them. You'd implement things like categories, tags, and "related" pages.

Then Googlebot would use the links between the pages on your site to crawl all your content.  After crawling, Google **might** choose to index your content in its search engine if it thinks it is high enough quality and your site has a good reputation.